# List of apps and services?

Tags: python, dataset

I was looking for a list of apps and services. I need this so I can search through a database of reviews and see what apps and services people mention so I can keep track of them. For example "The app does not work with netflix on" I need a word list that has things like "netflix, craigslist, amazon, etc" so i can keep track. I searched and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Back in the early 90s, people used to try to keep lists of everything on the web (even publishing it in a yearly book printed on dead trees), but nowadays that would be an impossible task. However you try to define "apps" and "services", there are millions of them, and people create new ones every day. The vast majority of those won't be of any interest to you (or your users); many won't even be accessible to you. Even some of the huge ones. But how could any centralized service know which ones you care about?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to just write the list up yourself. This is not likely something someone would create and it seems to have no real world implications.